# Is there a way to pass a Python variable string into gettext function _()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gettext

Is there a way to pass a variable string into gettext function `_()`?

Like:

```
my_str = 'Hello, World!'
print(_(my_str ))
```

This does not work when I run pygettext.
How can I fix it?

```
my_str = 'Hello, World!'
print(_(my_str ))
```

I expect to have as output of pygettext, in the .po file

```
.
.
.
msgid "Hello, World!"
msgstr ""
.
.
.
```

Comment: `mystr` is not `m_str`.

Comment: thx, I fixed it, it's just a typo ;)

Comment: `gettext` should work with string variables, but you can't expect the `pygettext.py` program to do so because it just analyzes your source code without running it.

Comment: There's no such way. It's an XY problem. Why do you need that feature? What's your goal? Anyway, if you insist generating po messages dynamically, just implement a script to generate a Python dummy source containing dummy ```_()``` calls.

Comment: Re *"This does not work"*: Can you be more specific? For example, what happens? What is the symptom?